# Updating .txt files with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

Okay so I've got a lot of movies... I wrote a thingy in the bat file to write all the movie names into a text file. So far it works fine but I noticed that if there are 2 or more movies a folder it doesn't write those files' names to the text file, for example in the folder Fast and Furious which has 5 files inside it, it doesn't write their names to the text file.

My current program line looks like this:
**`dir d:\Movies\ /b/on > d:\Movies.txt`**

I would like to know what I should do so it would write the file names of those which is more than 2 files in a folder, to the text file as well please.

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: try with `/s` option .It will search in sub directories.

Answer (score 1):

`dir "D:\Movies\" /b /a:-d /o:n /s > "D:\Movies.txt"`

`/s` will search the sub-directories.

`/a:-d` will remove any empty directories from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir C:\MyTest\ /s/b/on > C:\MyTest\ok.txt
```